# How to get selecteditem of a ASP.Net core select element

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dropdown

I have a `List<Incident>` which I get by calling an API and use it to populate a `select` element in a ASP.Net core MVC app. I would like to get the selected `Incident` and display the value of its `Option` property in a label.

In the View I have the following:

```
@model List<Incident>
@{
    var incidents = (List<Incident>)ViewData["incidents"];
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dashboard";
}

<select class="browser-default custom-select mb-2">
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    @foreach (var incident in @incidents)
    {
        <option value="@incident.id">@incident.Name</option>
    }
</select>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">@SelectedIncident.Option</label> CAN THIS BE DONE?
</div>
```

The controller's code is like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var incidents = await GetIncidentsAsync();
    ViewData[nameof(incidents)] = incidents;
    return View(incidents);
}
```

The incident class is:

```
public class Incident
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OtherDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Can this be done without a post-back to the server? Something like Syncfusion's [DropDownList](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/DropDownList/DefaultFunctionalities#/material).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple method is to set the `Option` property value of each option to  id attribute, and then use jquery to get the id of the selected item and assign it to lable

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select mb-2" id="ddlIncidents">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  @foreach (var incident in @incidents)
  {
    <option id="@incident.Option" value="@incident.Id">@incident.Name</option>
  }
</select>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked" id="selectedItem"></label>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
 <script>   
  $("#ddlIncidents").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    console.log(value);
    $("#selectedItem").text(value);
  });

 </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]